# How to start executing of Kotlin Coroutine immediately

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope

I want to start a coroutine immediately. I have a piece of code:

```
class SampleActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {

    private var job: Job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Log.d("SampleActivity", "Before launch")

        launch {
            Log.d("SampleActivity", "Inside coroutine")
        }

        Log.d("SampleActivity", "After launch")
    }
}
```

The **Output** is:

```
Before launch
After launch
Inside coroutine
```

Is it possible to achieve the output in the following order?

```
Before launch
Inside coroutine
After launch
```

Comment: why do you want to start coroutines immediately?

Comment: launch { } are fire and forget they return immediately a job, and the coroutine is free to take as long to finished as it needs. If you want to suspend the current thread while some work is done and then continue, then you must already be inside a coroutine this will allow you to suspend the execution while you wait for some result.

Comment: @Choim The screen is blinking in my app when user opens it while data from DB is being loaded. I guess launching a coroutine immediately will fix the problem.

Comment: can you tell the reason why do u wanna start it immediately ? any use case ? @Sergey

Comment: @Sergey blinking screen must not be caused by coroutines which is not executed immediately. I think of you doing something incorrectly.

Comment: You should use live data for that and setup the UI to be updated when data is ready. This way even if something goes wrong or the device is slow the app will look smooth.

Comment: @SantanuSur please see my comment above. 
Choim, My guess is that if launching a coroutine is delayed then loading of data from DB is also delayed. And that's why I have an empty screen (with no data) for a short period of time.

Comment: @Sergey please use some loaders or `progress bars` in that case.. before launching the coroutine and **stop it.. after execution of the async work**

Comment: Thanks @SantanuSur, but my customer is very picky, he doesn't like short time `progress bars` and `progress dialogs`.

Comment: In that case **even** if you start it immediately , *you never know that your work would be executed at the same speed in all devices .. especially with lower memory devices* @Sergey ( starting it immediately would also make the screen blink in that case depending upon the phone)

Comment: @SantanuSur, right, but I should give a try since now most modern devices have a lot of memory.

Comment: @Sergey you have to use some progress bars. if your customer dislike short time progress bars, how about splash screen for pre-loading to avoid it...?

Comment: @Choim thanks, but this is not a very good idea for my case, because there can be a lot of data in DB, and at specific point of time I need only some small piece of it, for example one row from a specific table. And I don't know in advance what row I need to load.

Comment: I think you are going all wrong about this. Maker sure your layout looks good even if there is no data (use placeholders). After the data is loaded just bind it to the views You can even add a nice transition using delayedTransition(). You cannot decide how fast your data is loaded is a hardware problem. This way if the data is available immediately the placeholders won't even show, there will be no flicker and if device is slow then you will have a nice transition when data is added.

Comment: Thanks @Mihai, I thought about using transitions and placeholders, but the customer is very picky, and he wants to switch screens fast. I have to display some data, e.g. `phone   1111111111`, but the placeholder in that case wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: When i say place holder i don't mean extra layouts or fake data. just make the layout look correct if there is no data. Dimensions, ratios ...etc. and when the data is available you set it to the view. You don't do anything to the views before the data is available.(all major apps do it like this Instagram, Facebook, etc..). You won't see any flicker but on some devices you will see a transition between no data and data.

Comment: @Mihai that's how I've already done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to launch it with:

`launch(Dispatchers.Main.immediate)`

More info in [this](https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/launching-a-kotlin-coroutine-for-immediate-execution-on-the-main-thread-8555e701163b) article.

Comment: There's also `launch(start = UNDISPATCHED)`, where you don't have to redeclare the dispatcher you're using. It's "the old way" and marked as experimental as well. This feature doesn't yet have its final form. However, given your input in the comments under the question, this will do nothing to solve your problem because the timing difference is negligible. The only relevant effect of this change is in the _guaranteed ordering_ of actions before the first suspension point (i.e., the execution order of the initial continuation).

Comment: Thanks @MarkoTopolnik, I will give a try and if it's not working I will consider some other approaches for my case.